# AJAX form redirecting on submit when using CKeditor

Tags: ajax, laravel, ckeditor

I am trying to submit an AJAX form with Laravel using the code shown below. After I submit the form, all the data is saved in the database as expected apart from the following field which is displayed as NULL in the database.

```
<textarea name="content" id="editor"></textarea>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

$(".btn-submit-add-video").each(function(){
  $(this).on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let form = $(this).closest('form');

    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success:function(data){
        alert(data.successful);
      }
    });
  })
});
</script>

public function addVideo(Request $request)
    {
        $addVideo = new cms_videos;
        $addVideo->VideoStatus = $request->VideoStatus;
        $addVideo->VideoTitle = $request->VideoTitle;
        $addVideo->VideoStrapline = $request->VideoStrapline;
        $addVideo->VideoURL = $request->VideoURL;
        $addVideo->VideoDescription = $request->content;
        $addVideo->VideoTags = $request->VideoTags;
        $addVideo->MetaActName = $request->MetaActName;
        $addVideo->MetaRegion = $request->MetaRegion;
        $addVideo->MetaGenre = $request->MetaGenre;
        $addVideo->MetaVenue = $request->MetaVenue;
        $addVideo->VideoCoverPhoto = $request->VideoCoverPhoto;
        $addVideo->save();

        return response()->json(['successful'=>'Video successfully added']);
    }
```

After doing some research I was told to add the following code to the top of the code shown above:
CKEDITOR.instances.SurveyBody.updateElement();

Now all the data is submitted to the database as expected. However when I now submit the form instead of an alert popping up saying "Successful" I am now redirected to the form action URL where it displays "Successful". How can I stop this redirection and display the alert on the page the form was submitted?

Comment: Please add your controller code here as well

Comment: Hi Tohid, I've edited my original post to include the controller code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think the issue is here when you do e.preventDefault() because it works for the button click not for form submission. Try this out and hope it will help you.

**Notice:** you have to add *upload_video* class to your forms

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
// If the button is type of submit you can remove this part of code
$(".btn-submit-add-video").each(function(){
    $(this).on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let form = $(this).closest('form.upload_video');
        form.submit();
    })
});
//
$("form.upload_video").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this),data=form.serialize();
    //
    let content=FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('content').getData();
    data['content']=content;
    //
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: data,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data.successful);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This part

> let content=FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('content').getData();

May not be true because I don't work with CKEDITOR right now and i can't test it but you can console.log() it before you send the ajax request and make sure the content exists in the variable as you expected.

Comment: It works but once again the "content" field is NULL. Once I add:
CKEDITOR.instances.SurveyBody.updateElement();
below the ajax setup it then saves the value of content but redirects on form submission again.

Comment: Open the console and make sure there is no any javaScript error otherwise it disallows the remaining code to work.

Comment: I updated the code to get the content of the CKEDITOR, I think you have to get its content dynamically and add it to your form request data

Comment: Nothing is working, every time I manage to save the data from the CKeditor the redirect occurs.

Comment: I swapped the text editor to summer note and its working fine now!